# Visualising relationship data

Tags: data-visualization, matrix, social-network

I have data about a certain workforce, with different worker types W1, W2, W3, W4, etc. I need a method to visualise the relationship between each worker type. In particular, I'm interested in visualising the proportion of each worker type (e.g., W1, W2, W3, etc.) that works with each other worker type.

Essentially, assuming there are 10 worker types, I'm looking at a 10x10 matrix. I could visualise it like these:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLIoT.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvrLq.png]

...but I'm open to any other ideas. Those two diagrams require programs that I find difficult to use. I'm looking for something more appealing than a matrix with coloured cells.

Answer (score 5):

There is much of relevance at

[Graph for relationship between two ordinal variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56322/graph-for-relationship-between-two-ordinal-variables/)

The detail there of using ordinal variables does not bite with your problem where the workers are just different.

You might need to expand on "appealing": there is often tension here between clever and unusual but difficult to decode and basic and simple but easy to decode.