# Best way to visualise / respresent complex relationships / hierarchies

Tags: data-visualization, presentation

I'm trying to visualise relations, i.e. of which "parts" (e.g. products, technologies etc.) a website is built upon.

[image: components of a website]

I was thinking of a chord diagram (maybe built with d3.js so the viewer can hover about a specific field and the rest will be greyed out). Do you think this is a good idea? Like here: [Visualising relationship data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59689/visualising-relationship-data)

**My final goal:** My client can navigate through his interdependent portfolio (e.g. by hovering over a category or component) and understand where a component is used.

Comment: It often helps to get useful meaningful answers if you provide some typical data. And it would be good to point out how you problem differs from the ones seen by following the link.

Comment: the whole image is the data :)
an example could be: website a1 delivers content to website b2, b3. it has app 8 and 14 incorporated; and a twitter channel.

Comment: @AmirRahbaran If the image is the data, why is it not also a sufficient visualization of the data for your purposes?

Comment: @Kodiologist: thx for your question. because the "relationship arrows" are missing (e.g., as in a chord diagram). i want to show how the websites are intertwined and composed of different apps, content, social media etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the data structure you want to visualize is at heart a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), in the sense of graph theory. So your best bet is a generic graph visualizer, such as GraphViz. Play with the options until the result makes sense.

Comment: Thx for the link. I think I'm going to try the graph with design elements of a chord diagramm.

Comment: `git` allows to visually see differences and one can use develop the base website to then use `git` to upload the initial code. Then modules can be adapted and also pushed to `git`.

If one is using multi-relationships, association rules chart with `R` library `arules` can also be a way to show different components and link them using probabilities. Maybe this adds a bit of uniqueness to it.