# What kind of chart to use when comparing two sets of data, each with an X and Y?

Tags: data-visualization, group-differences

So I did a survey for a class at school, and I am looking for a correlation between how often people read the news, and their opinion on a certain current event.

People rated their up-to-dateness on a scale of 1 to 5, so I have a set of data with number of students who are in each category (1,2,3,4,5 are the categories).

I also have a set of data for their opinion on the current event, it was multiple choice with 4 answer choices. So I have a set of data with the number of students in each category (I changed each answer choice to an integer 1 to 4).

What is the best way to present this information in a way that it will be clear what the relation is, if any?

Comment: Is their opinion of the current event an ordinal variable or a nominal variable?

Comment: Many relevant threads here. See e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56322/graph-for-relationship-between-two-ordinal-variables

Answer (score 0):

In order to visually inspect the data, I'd first make a stacked vertical bar plot of the two variables, easy to do in Excel.

Plot the up-to-dateness scale on the x-axis and the % breakout of the current event opinions on the y-axis.