# Validity of Wilcoxon Signed Rank or Spearman for 2 Likert Scales

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank, spearman-rho

I am working on my MSc dissertation findings and I have data results from two 5-Point Likert scales. One Likert measured self-assessed behaviour, whilst the other measured attitude. (Both scales were labelled strongly disagree to strongly agree).

My hypothesis is that respondents who attributed a high score on one Likert will do the same on the other Likert.

Both population samples were the same (i.e. I distributed one survey, and the same respondents filled in both Likert scales at one point in time), so I understand that I must carry out a related samples tests.

Would I be correct in using Wilcoxon signed rank test?

I tried charting a scatterplot and carrying out correlation analysis but the output doesn't seem to make sense:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried applying Spearman's but the first step is to determine if there is a monotonic relationship. With the dataset I have (17 responses), I'm having a hard time interpreting the scatterplot depicted above.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you have a larger sample that scatterplot might not be very helpful. You have limited number of categories in each variable. Maybe a different visualization helps, see this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56322/graph-for-relationship-between-two-ordinal-variables). For small samples, some people recommend Kendall's Tau but I am not sure.

Comment: And sorry I deleted my previous comment by accident (on mobile).

Comment: Thank you!! I was thinking of carrying out a visualization instead of statistical testing, but I couldn't find different types of visualizations techniques. I'll try a heat map instead and see if my tutor is fine with it.